# How to use join in linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

I did one small application of contact system for add update and delete.Now making group of this contacts here I am using XML as datasource.Now want to join two xml files one contact.xml and other is group.xml.

I got this really useful.

DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
  DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();

```
         ds1.ReadXml("Contact.xml");
         ds2.ReadXml("Group.xml");

         DataTable dt1 = ds1.Tables[0];
         DataTable dt2 = ds2.Tables[0];


         var groups = from contact in dt.AsEnumerable()
                      join ol in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                      on contact.Field<string>("ID") equals ol.Field<string>("ID")

                    select new
                    { FName=ol.Field<string>("FName")
                                        };
```

Comment: Can you post small examples of the 2 xml files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply this way:

```
var q = from c in customers
        join o in orders on c.Key equals o.Key
        select new {c.Name, o.OrderNumber};
```

Refer to the following tutorial about *LINQ*:

http://www.asp.net/linq/videos

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Its really simple.